# What is the domain of $ \log_{2}(x \log_{\frac12}(y-x)) $?

Tags: analysis, functions, multivariable-calculus

I should also give the plot of the domain, I know that $ \log_{2}$ has to be bigger, than zero, how can I continue the problem solving?

Comment: I assume that $y>x$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to he other answers, here is a plot of the domain plotting $xlog_{1/2}(y-x)\gt 0$ in Desmos:

[image]

Comment: Using programms to solve stuff is usually not accepted in mathematics schools around the world in most decent universities...

Comment: @DonAntonio On exams, no. But to explain concepts, there's nothing wrong w/ using programmes. Computer graphs can help solidify understanding.

Comment: DonAntonio I solved it the same way as you, but your answer was earlier so I checked with Desmos. In fact, as MathematicsStudent1122 has said, the thin strip on the right corresponds with $x\gt 0$ and $0\lt y-x\lt 1$ and the region on the right is $x\lt 0$ and $y\gt x+1$ so the visualization can help sometimes...

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 I can't understand how this can possibily help the OP to **deduce** what the domain is. It can, true, help to see it geometrically or to support what he did **after** the domain has been obtained analytically.

Comment: @pedro Then perhaps adding the legend  "this is *only* to check* could help, and maybe only as a comment.

Comment: @DonAntonio "In addition to the other answers". I didn´t say it was a solution

Comment: @Pedro Good point.

Answer (score 4):

Lets first start with the inside and work our way outside, so $\log_{1/2} (y - x)$. This only exists if $y - x >0 \implies y > x$

Now for the outside part  $\log_2(x\log_{1/2} (y - x))$ which is valid for $x\log_{1/2} (y - x) > 0$. Now this is true in 2 cases.

Case 1: Both are positive. This means $x> 0$  and $y - x < 1 \implies x < y < 1 + x$ so for $x> 0$ then $y$ must be between $x$ and $1 + x$

Case 2: Both are negative. This means $x < 0$ and $y - x > 1 \implies y > x + 1$ so for $x < 0$ $y$ must be greater than $1$

Comment: In your case (1), also $\;x>0\;,\;\;y-x=0.9\;$ is true...why did you decide to take $\;1/2\;$ in both cases?

Comment: @DonAntonio You are right I've edited my answer. Sorry for the silly mistakes

Comment: Any time...but as you could see, two persons thought it was a nice option to upvote. Let us just hope you won't get now downvotes with the right answer... :)

Comment: Haha, quite true actually I'm surprised they haven't noticed the errors!

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

Make some sense of the following, and fill in details

$$y>x\;,\;\;x\log_{1/2}(y-x)>0\implies\begin{cases}x>0\;\;\text{and}\;\;y-x<1\\{}\\\text{or}\\{}\\x<0\;\;\text{and}\;\;y-x>1\end{cases}$$